# How to sort and remove the repeat URLs(the file contain about ten billion URLs)!

Tags: sorting, nlp, search-engine, bigdata

As the title said, how to sort the file? If you PC's memory is just 2GB, but there are ten billion URLs(assume that the longest URL is 256 chars).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little vague, but I'm assuming :

1. You have a flat file containing many URLs.
2. The URLs are delimited somehow, I'm assuming newlines.
3. You want to create a separate file without duplicates.

### Possible solutions :

1. Write code to read each URL in turn from the file, and insert into a relational database. Make the primary key be the URL, and any duplicates will be rejected.
2. Build your own index. This is a little more complex. You would need to use something like a disk-based btree implementation. Then read each URL, and add it to the disk-based BTree. Again, check for duplicates as you add to the tree.

However, given all the free database systems out there, solution 1 is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a lot of data, then `Hadoop` either is, or should be on your radar.
In that HDFS is used to store the huge volume of data and also be a lot of tools for query with that data.
In HDFS the data processing is very effective and fast. you can use the No-sql tool like Hive and also other tool like Pig,etc.
Now the YAHOO using the Big-Data technology for huge amount of data processing. Also Hadoop 
is open source.
Refer `http://hadoop.apache.org/` for more.